# can not enable ts-check in jsconfig.json in vsc?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

if I put `//@ts-check` in a file, it checks the code, but if I use following `jsconfig.json`, it won't check, why? I am using vscode version 1.15.1

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check the code"? Looks for syntax errors? What extension are you using to do that?

Comment: if i put //@ts-check in the source code, I can see some warnings in the IDE about the code, that's good, so instead of doing this in every file in the project, I specified checkJs:true in the jsconfig.json, hoping I can have those  warnings

Comment: maybe I read it wrong, in the link below it says ts-check per file, or jsconfig.json per setting:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript

Comment: I think that works for all projects, I want only a particular project, did make it work, steps : jsconfig.json and tsconfig.json as specified in the above link, re-launch vscode, go to a .js file, wait a while to see the warning, the warning will not come out instantly in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [VS Code docs on Javascript](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript):

> To enable type checking for all JavaScript files without changing any
>   code, just add `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true` to
>   your workspace or user settings. This enables type checking for any
>   JavaScript file that is not part of a `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json`
>   project.

You must add `"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true` to your `jsconfig.json` file for the linting to work.

Comment: But in the [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) it is said that there are three *alternative* ways of enabling type checking: Per file, Using a setting (you suggested), and Using jsconfig or tsconfig (which the OP asked about). Therefore, your answer actually does not actually answer the question: why `jsconfig` setting does not enable type checking in all the files. I also face this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true` goes in VSCode's `settings.json`, *not* your project's `jsconfig.json`.

The `jsconfig.json` option is `"checkJs": true`.